# When does data load in ASP .NET control?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on a ASP .NET control (for Blackbaud's NetCommunity system) that needs to load data from the database, then update some controls' enabled state based on the data that has been loaded.  From what I can see according to Microsoft's page lifecycle, the appropriate place to change this is during the Page_PreRenderComplete event, but this doesn't seem to work, so I'm guessing that I am wrong.  However, I don't know for sure since I can't see where the actual database retrieval is taking place.  I have two drop downs on this control that determine what data is shown in a grid below, and the grid needs to change its state based on the data inside.  Do I need to figure out how to load the data early, and then make my state updates, or is there somewhere I can make the updates late and still have it render properly?

Comment: Are these databound controls? What about the DataBound event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Page_PreRenderComplete** is too late to manipulate a control. Normally, we use **PreRender** event.

However, if you want to manipulate controls located inside **GridView**, you want to use GridView's [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event in which you can find controls using **FindControl**.

For example,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      var textbox = e.Row.FindControl("MyTextBox") as TextBox;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to read from the control?  I've just been directly reading from the data set.

Comment: You can get the rest of the data inside RowDataBound by casting DataItem to DataRowView this - `DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; var data = rowView["MyColumnName"].ToString();`